# Global Variables Return Unexpected Values

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, global

Well I was trying to assign global variable to read values from Check boxes and radio buttons but the values don't update when the selections are changed ! Where have I done wrong? Here's the code:

```
private void chkInMut_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalVar.Mutate = 1;
    }

    private void chkShwCal_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalVar.ShowCal = 1;
    }

    private void chkOutSol_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalVar.OutCal = 1;
    }
}

public static class GlobalVar
{
    static int _MaxMin, _MutVal, _CalShow, _CalOut;

    /// <summary>
    /// Access routine for global variable.
    /// </summary>

    public static int Extrema
    {
        get
        {
            return _MaxMin;
        }
        set
        {
            _MaxMin = value;
        }
    }

    public static int Mutate
    {
        get
        {
            return _MutVal;
        }
        set
        {
            _MutVal = value;
        }

    }

    public static int ShowCal
    {
        get
        {
            return _CalShow;
        }
        set
        {
            _CalShow = value;
        }
    }

    public static int OutCal
    {
        get
        {
            return _CalOut;
        }
        set
        {
            _CalOut = value;
        }
    }
}
```

when I try to print the numbers using this test satement, the values returned are unexpected :

```
        maxMin = GlobalVar.Extrema;
        calShow = GlobalVar.ShowCal;
        calOut = GlobalVar.OutCal;
        IsMutble = GlobalVar.Mutate;
        txtOutput.Text += Convert.ToString("\nMaxima Minima"+maxMin+"\n"+"Show Cal : "+calShow+"\n"+"Output Cal :"+calOut+"\n"+"Mutate : "+IsMutble+"\n---------\n");
```

And when I check/un-check the boxes, the values are not updated as it should be. Where have I gone wrong?

**Edit:** Solved by adding Unchecked Parameter.

Comment: Put only the related parts of code, but not a wall of code :)

Comment: Using automatically implemented properties would make your `GlobalVar` class body just three lines long... not that I'd recommend using global variables in the first place...

Comment: Uhm, you set always 1 in the checked event both for checked or unchecked. You get always 1 as result?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks. What would be your recommendation?

Comment: @Jeet.Deir: Well we don't know enough about what you're trying to achieve - but global variables are almost *never* the right solution. You should look at tutorials for the MVVM pattern though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the heads up. I will go through MVVM pattern tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should write your event handlers like this

```
private void chkInMut_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GlobalVar.Mutate = (chkInMut.IsChecked ? 1 : 0);
}
```

and so on .....

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your public static properties. for example try this:

```
public static int Extrema
{
    get
    {
        return GlobalVar._MaxMin;
    }
    set
    {
        GlobalVar._MaxMin = value;
    }
}
```

and do the same for all other properties.

**Edit:**
and why are you using this stucture? You can set your static class to be like this:

```
public static class GlobalVar
{
   public static int Extrema;
   public static int Mutate;
     public static int ShowCal;
}
```

Comment: This link might you [Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I would *not* suggest using public fields. Global properties are bad enough, but public fields would be worse...